# How to return the list of all previous 30 days in MySQL even with no records?

Tags: mysql, date, mariadb

I have a table which stores support tickets. I need to show some statistical data on charts. In one of these charts, I want to show the historical data about received tickets during all previous 30 days.
Imagine that the structure of main ticket is like this:

**tickets table:**

| ticket_id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-03-21 |
| 2 | 2021-03-21 |
| 3 | 2021-03-25 |
| 4 | 2021-03-26 |
| 5 | 2021-03-27 |
| 6 | 2021-03-27 |
| 7 | 2021-03-28 |

At the end, I need the list of previous 30 days with the quantity of total tickets in each one. Something like this:

.
.
.
2021-03-21 > 2
2021-03-22 > 0
2021-03-23 > 0
2021-03-24 > 0
2021-03-25 > 1
2021-03-26 > 1
2021-03-27 > 2
2021-03-28 > 1
2021-03-29 > 0
.
.
.

I could retrieve the list of tickets in the previous 30 days, but couldn't find the days with 0 tickets. On the other hands, there are not any records on such days, but I need to have a complete list of 30 previous days.  May you help me please?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2):

You could use calendar table:

```
WITH calendar (
  SELECT '2021-03-01' + INTERVAL (seq) DAY AS d
  FROM seq_0_to_400
)
SELECT c.d, COUNT(t.date)
FROM calendar c
LEFT JOIN tickets t
  ON c.d = t.date
WHERE c.d BETWEEN ... AND ...;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=61351122ee9901540bd60ef37a80a09b)**

Comment: Thanks @Lukasz, but when I run this code I received this error: `> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'calendar AS (...`

Comment: @MohammadSaberi Please check the MariaDB verion.It may not support sequence.

Comment: I've checked it but did not find any difference between MySQL and MariaDB. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/with/#examples